# What do the words "undefined" mean in bullet point §5.19/2.3 in N4140?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, constexpr, constant-expression

From [N4140](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf) §5.19/2.3 (emphasis mine)

> — an invocation of an **undefined** constexpr function or an
>   **undefined** constexpr constructor;

From §7.1.5/2 constexpr functions and constructors are implicitly inlined, that is, if a constexpr function is not defined in a TU the code will just not compile.

Comment: *"the code will just not compile"* Isn't this just a violation of the ODR?

Comment: As a violation of the ODR, this is UB with No Diagnostic Required - but since it's UB, I'd guess it violates the rule "no UB in constant expressions"?

Comment: I would guess it refers to *undefined prior to the constant expression*, to disallow examples like: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9afaa2abe2ea46e7

Comment: @dyp I think you've got the answer with your example in coliru.

Comment: Well, Shafik Yaghmour found proof, I was only speculating :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bullet was added by [defect report 699](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3383.html#699) and it requires that a constexpr function or constructor must be defined before use. The defect report added the following example to `7.1.5` to demonstrate the rule:

```
constexpr int square(int x);       //OK, declaration
constexpr struct pixel {           // error: pixel is a type
    int x;
    int y;
    constexpr pixel(int);            // OK, declaration
};
constexpr pixel::pixel(int a)
    : x(square(a)), y(square(a)) { } //OK, definition
constexpr pixel small(2);          // error: square not defined, so small(2)
                                     // not constant (5.19 [expr.const]), so constexpr not satisfied
constexpr int square(int x) {      // OK, definition
    return x * x;
}
constexpr pixel large(4);          // OK, square defined
```

Note, the wording from this report changed with [defect report 1365](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3383.html#1365) to the wording currently in the draft standard.